# How do I append an <li> element to an existing <ul> using jquery?

Tags: jquery, xml

I have a list of urls in an XML file, and I am trying to loop through each one and add them to an unordered list.  The code I have below works, but, when it displays on the page only one of the urls actually displays as a link. Is there a better way to do this, that will make it display as it should?

```
function getXMLDetails(itemName) {
$.ajax({
    url: 'getDetailsX.xml',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(xml) {
        $('#description').empty();
        $(xml).find('item').each(function() {
            if($(this).find('name').text() === itemName) {
                var description = '<p>Description: ' + $(this).find('description').text() + '</p>';
                var price = '<p>Price: $' + $(this).find('price').text() + '</p>';
                var list = '<ul>';
                $(this).find('url').each(function() {
                    list += '<li><a href=' + $(this).text() + '>' + $(this).text() + '</a></li>');
                });
                list += '</ul>';
                $('#description').append(description, price, list);
            }
        });
    }
});

}
```

This is how it's displaying:

[image]

And this is how it's supposed to display:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Append  outside for each loop.Like this.It may help.

```
 var list = '<ul>';
        $(xml).find('item').each(function() {
            if($(this).find('name').text() === itemName) {
                var description = '<p>Description: ' + $(this).find('description').text() + '</p>';
                var price = '<p>Price: $' + $(this).find('price').text() + '</p>';

                $(this).find('url').each(function() {
                    list += '<li><a href=' + $(this).text() + '>' + $(this).text() + '</a></li>');
                });

                $('#description').append(description, price, list);
            }
        });
        list += '</ul>';
```